# No connection between the two containers

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, fetch, traefik

I have two containers that must connect to each other,
but when I want to fetch data from another container get `ENOTFOUND` error!
this code works on my local system but does not work in the container!

`error log`

```
FetchError: request to http://user.localhost/accessticketing failed, reason: getaddrinfo

ENOTFOUND user.localhost
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///E:/Programming/map/microservices/ticketing/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  erroredSysCall: 'getaddrinfo'
}
```

`docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.7
    container_name: 'Traefik'
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
  user:
    build: './microservices/User'
    container_name: 'User'
    volumes:
      - ./db/user:/db
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.user.rule=Host(`user.localhost`)"
  pv:
    build: './microservices/pv'
    container_name: 'pv'
    volumes:
      - ./db/Project-vendee:/db
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.pv.rule=Host(`pv.localhost`)"
```

`my code`

```js
 try {
    const response = await fetch("http://user.localhost/accessticketing", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      redirect: "follow",
      referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
      body: JSON.stringify({ Token }),
    });
    const massage: any = await response.json();
    return massage;
  } catch (error: SmartError | undefined | any) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error.type === "system" && error.erroredSysCall === "connect") {
      throw { code: 501, maasage: "Unable to connect to the user section" };
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The two containers do not know each other,
so it would help if you used the same network!**

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.7
    container_name: 'Traefik'
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
  user:
    build: './microservices/User'
    container_name: 'User'
    volumes:
      - ./db/user:/db
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.user.rule=Host(`user.localhost`)
      - traefik.docker.network=my-network
  pv:
    build: './microservices/pv'
    container_name: 'pv'
    volumes:
      - ./db/Project-vendee:/db
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.pv.rule=Host(`pv.localhost`)
      - traefik.docker.network=my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    external : true
```

> Soon I will edit this answer and tell you more about networking on Docker, but it works for you right now.